# refactoring my rails code (model method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So this works fine, it's just I need some refactoring done. What I want to achieve is, get all the values for the current record or just put another column (calculated column, like in SQL) that'll hold all the values for all of my fields that starts with "address".

So far, this is what I have.

Thanks for any input. Also, if possible, do not post the actual refactored code, but just let me know what I should be reading or just hints. I prefer achieving this on my own. Thanks again.

```
  def address
    "#{self[:address_street1]} #{self[:address_street2]} #{self[:address_city]} #{self[:address_state]} #{self[:address_zipcode]} #{self[:address_country]}"
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `self[:foo]` to access the `foo` field on a particular model. If this is a column on your database, within the code of the class itself, you can just use `foo`

```
def print_foo
  # not this
  # puts self[:foo]

  # use this instead
  puts foo
end
```

So, to simplify your address a bit

```
def address
  [
    address_street1,
    address_street2,
    address_city,
    address_state,
    address_zipcode,
    address_country
  ].join(" ")
end
```

Another method is to use [String#%](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-25)

```
def address
  %Q{
    %s
    %s
    %s, %s %s
    %s
  } % [
    address_street1,
    address_street2,
    address_city,
    address_state,
    address_zipcode,
    address_country
  ]
end
```

This would result in output like

```
123 Main St
Apt 456
Seattle, WA 98122
USA
```

However, if one or more of the address components are empty, you might want remove them. To do that, you could do something like this

```
def address
  [
    address_street1,
    address_street2,
    address_city,
    address_state,
    address_zipcode,
    address_country
  ].reject(&:blank?).join(" ")
end
```

All of that said, I think it would probably be better to separate addresses into their own `Address` model and separate table entirely. This would give you lots more flexibility around managing your addresses and dealing with some other complexities. The `Address` model could handle all of the formatting if you like, which means you wouldn't have to clutter up your (presumable) `User` model with all of this address logic.

Not to mention, a variety of models may have addresses; not just Users. As an example, Orders have billing/shipping addresses, Credit Cards have a billing address, Users could have multiple addresses, or Users could even have their own Contacts where they're managing addresses other than their own. If each resource needing an address had to have `address_*` fields directly on their database table, this would get out of control pretty quickly.

Comment: don't forget the space in the join(' '), I think stack overflow strips it out.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I was eventually going to create a different model for it. Initially I did so, but I ran to many problems during my first week learning rails so I just went basic. Thanks for the answers. Very cool!

Comment: I seem to be having some issues, when I did your method it's telling me none of those fields are initialized.